# wrapping text around an image on top of the page

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, wrap, report, wrapfig

For my university report, i have to create this in latex.
[image]

I tried it on latex using wragfig with this code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin={25mm,25mm},hmargin={25mm,20mm}]{geometry}\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,wrapfig,tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
%border
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=2pt,rounded corners=2pt,]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (15mm,-9mm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-9mm,9mm) $);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 %borderend
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.2\textwidth}
 %\centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{logo.png}
 % logo.png: 1068x1024 px, 72dpi, 37.68x36.12 cm, bb=0 0 1068 1024
\end{wrapfigure}
\centering
  {\Large \color{blue!50!gray} SARDAR VALLABHBHAI NATIONAL INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY\\ [3mm] SURAT-395007, GUJRAT, INDIA\\[3.5mm] \bfseries DEPARTMENT OF ELECTRICAL ENGINEERING}\\

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue!50!gray, ultra thick] (0,0) -- (16,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \vspace{5mm}
 \par
\section*{\Huge \bfseries CERTIFICATE}


\lipsum
\end{document}
```

here is what i got

[image]

I again searched on internet and someone recommended to use tikz package. so here is what i did

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin={25mm,25mm},hmargin={25mm,20mm}]{geometry}\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,wrapfig,tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
%border
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=2pt,rounded corners=2pt,]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (15mm,-9mm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-9mm,9mm) $);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 %borderend
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{2.5cm}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] at ($(current page.north west)+(20mm,-34mm)$) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo.png}};
     \end{tikzpicture}
     % logo.png: 1068x1024 px, 72dpi, 37.68x36.12 cm, bb=0 0 1068 1024
    \end{wrapfigure}

\centering
      {\Large \color{blue!50!gray} SARDAR VALLABHBHAI NATIONAL INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY}\\
      [3mm]
      {\Large \color{blue!50!gray} SURAT-395007, GUJRAT, INDIA}\\
      [3.5mm]
      {\Large \color{blue!50!gray}\bfseries DEPARTMENT OF ELECTRICAL ENGINEERING}\\

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue!50!gray, ultra thick] (0,0) -- (16,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \vspace{5mm}
 \par
\section*{\Huge \bfseries CERTIFICATE}


\lipsum
\end{document}
```

and the output is still not what i desired
[image]

Somebody help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I would just use `minipage`. One for the logo, one for the main text, and one for the text on the right.

Comment: There is also the issue of whether to use the text area.  If the rest of the document uses a different size, I would put this whole page inside a minipage inside a node inside a tikzpicture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that the certificate does not fit into the text area for the rest of the document.  The `\certificate` savebox is mostly to avoid putting the page source inside the tikzpicture directly.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
%\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin={25mm,25mm},hmargin={25mm,20mm},showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox,graphicx,xcolor,tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newsavebox{\certificate}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%create certivicate
\savebox{\certificate}{\begin{minipage}[c][\dimexpr \paperheight-50mm][t]{\dimexpr \paperwidth-45mm}% entire page
  \sbox0{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}% logo.png
  \sbox1{\rotatebox[origin=br]{-90}{\resizebox{\ht0}{!}{\textcolor{blue}{\textsf{SVINT}}}}}% fit to logo
  \usebox0\begin{minipage}[b][\ht0][s]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd0-\wd1}
    \centering
      {\large \color{blue!50!gray} SARDAR VALLABHBHAI NATIONAL INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY}\par\vfill
      {\large \color{blue!50!gray} SURAT-395007, GUJRAT, INDIA}\par\vfill
      {\large \color{blue!50!gray}\bfseries DEPARTMENT OF ELECTRICAL ENGINEERING}
  \end{minipage}\usebox1\par
  \parindent=\bibindent
  \bigskip
  \centerline{\Huge \bfseries CERTIFICATE}
  \medskip
  \lipsum
\end{minipage}}%
%position with border
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [line width=2pt,rounded corners=2pt]
        ($ (current page.north west) + (15mm,-9mm) $)
        rectangle
        ($ (current page.south east) + (-9mm,9mm) $);
    \node[below right, inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north west) +(25mm,-25mm)$) {\usebox\certificate};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. Box and minipage is new for me so i will have to catchup on that. I have one question, i didnt get what you actually assumed?

Comment: This will work whether or not this page conforms to the standard page size (from geometry).  IIRC, the logo starts at the top of the header area.